# Azure DocumentDB Owner resource does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I having the same error icrosoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Owner resource does not exist"]} , this is my scenario. When I deployed my webapp to Azure and try to get some document from docDb it throws this error. The docdb exists in azure and contains the document that i looking for.

The weird is that from my local machine(running from VS) this works fine. I'm using the same settings in Azure and local. Somebody have and idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: According to the exception `"Errors":["Owner resource does not exist"]}`, it seems that the document is not existing in the collection. But you mentioned that it is existing. Do you have a try  [remote debug the WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps).  to check the documentId `Uri documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(
                databaseName,
                collectionName,
                documentId);`

Comment: I  just can repro the error info while the document is not existing the collection. Do  you have a try to config another documentdb  to test it?  As I  know there is no need to do  special configuration on the Azure WebApp. More detail please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-dotnet-application#a-nametoc395637774astep-7-deploy-the-application-to-azure-websites)

Answer (score 75):

> Owner resource does not exist

occurs when you have given a wrong database name.

For example, while reading a document with `client.readDocument(..)`, where the client is `DocumentClient` instance, the database name given in `docLink` is wrong.

Comment: The correct database name and container name are shown in Azure Portal / <your Cosmos DB> / Overview

Comment: I _think_ it's also case sensitive for the value of the DB name as well.

Answer (score 4):

This error for sure appears to be related to reading a database/collection/document which does not exist. I got the same exact error for a database that did exist but I input the name as lower case, this error appears to happen regardless of your partition key.

The best solution I could come up with for now is to wrap the

```
var response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, "documentid"));
```

call in a try catch, not very elegant and I would much rather the response comes back with some more details but this is Microsoft for ya.

Something like the below should do the trick.

```
                Model myDoc = null;

                try
                {
                    var response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, document));
                    myDoc = (Model )(dynamic)response.Resource;
                }
                catch { }


                if (myDoc != null)
                {
                   //do your work here
                }
```

That is to get a better idea of the error then create the missing resource so you dont get the error anymore.

A few resources I had to go through before coming to this conclusion:
https://github.com/DamianStanger/DocumentDbDemo

[Azure DocumentDB Read Document Resource Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612223/azure-documentdb-read-document-resource-not-found)

Comment: Note: it appears that database name is CASE-SENSITIVE. This was my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found that Visual Studio 2017 is publishing using my Release configuration instead of the Test configuration I've selected. **In my case the Release configuration had a different CosmosDB database name that doesn't exist**, which resulted in the "owner resource does not exist" error when I published to my Azure test server. Super frustrating and a terrible error message.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be caused by a not found attachment to a document.
This is a common scenario when you move cosmos db contents using [Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/updates/documentdb-data-migration-tool/) which moves all the documents with their complete definition but unfortunately not the real attachment content.

Therefore this result in a document that states it has an attachment, and also states the attachment link, but at that given link no attachment can be found because the tool have not moved it.

Now i wrap my code as follow

```
try{
    var attachments = client.CreateAttachmentQuery(attacmentLink, options);
    [...]
}
catch (DocumentClientException ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Cannot retrieve attachment of document", ex);
}
```

to have a meaningful hint of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this because my dependency injection configuration had two instances of `CosmosClient` being created for different databases. Thus any code trying to query the first database was running against the second database.

My fix was to create a `CosmosClientCollection` class with named instances of `CosmosClient`

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS if the database name has error:

```
const config = {
      endpoint: "/...",
      key: "...",
      databaseId: "data_base_name_error", // error in name: Owner resource does not exist
      connectionPolicy: { enableEndpointDiscovery: false }
    }
```