# Can't write dataframe in Cosmos DB / documentDB from Databricks with pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I get an error I don't understand when trying to save a dataframe I've been working on to a documentDB collection.

Others similar issues on stack pointed to incorrect or case sensitive names provided for the Database or the Collection But I Checked Those... What other explanations could there be ?  PartitionKey ? Region ?...

On an other hand I was unable to find a complete doc on which options were eventually to be provided to the line `df.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode('overwrite').options(**ddbconfig).save()`

Error given by Spark on Databricks is  :

```
com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: Message: {'Errors':['Owner resource does not exist']}
```

The StackTrace gave those

```
Py4JJavaError: 
  An error occurred while calling o646.save. :
    com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: 
      Message: {"Errors":["Owner resource does not exist"]}
```

Response gave in the storereadresult

```
LSN: 623, GlobalCommittedLsn: 623, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 404, IsGone: False, IsNotFound: True, IsInvalidPartition: False, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#623, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Read
```

edit : different situation than in similar linked posts. This error occuring when trying to write data in a new, empty collection. Not reading existing data. And I had already clarified in my question that I have explored every path (collection/database names mismatches mainly) that I had found in those similar posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure DocumentDB Owner resource does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551321/azure-documentdb-owner-resource-does-not-exist)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. The question you linked, which I had reviewed previous to my message, concerns a similar error message but a really different situation. It's a reading error, mine is a writing error. Additionnaly, In my question I noted that I checked any possible mismatch in database and collection names & case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating further, it's a bug in the version of the library I was using.

Resolved by switching from azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.2.2-uber.jar to azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.2.7-uber.jar

As seen here on github 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/issues/268